# Write a common method for all view controllers to adjust frame of content view (of UIScrollView) when keyboard appears

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my iOS app, there are almost 10 ViewControllers inside which UITextFields are present.
I implemented functionality of shifting content view upwards when keyboard appears.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

This site explains all.

But my problem is that I have to repeat the same code inside every View Controller. Is their any way so that I can write common class or method which works with all my 10 ViewControllers, so that reusability in code can be achieved?

From the apple doc, I have to use following methods. But I am stuck at a place where I have to pass instance of scrollview and active text field (For each view controller, these instances are different) to my common class/method.

```
// Call this method somewhere in your view controller setup code.
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
            selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
            name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
 
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
 
}
 
// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
 
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
 
    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your app might not need or want this behavior.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:activeField.frame animated:YES];
    }
}
 
// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeField = textField;
}
 
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeField = nil;
}
```

Comment: create one method in one class and that class you have to managing notification scrollview content and in appdelagate.m file  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
            selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
            name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
 
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil]; write this 2 method.

Comment: You could create a subclass.... then write anything which is common behavior in it.

Comment: create a base class that all viewControllers will adhere to?

Comment: You can use a lib like [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) or [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager), should be much easier

Comment: @Himanshu Moradiya - Can you post some more details in answer section? But how I can send instance of scroll view placed insite each view controller

Comment: @Joshua and Chiquis - I have already inherited all my view comtrollers from base view controllers. But I got problem that how to send instance of scrollview from each view controller to base view controller

Comment: Create property in base view controller for scrollView and initialize it in viewDidLoad method of each derived view controllers. Also move activeField property to base view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create property in base view controller for scrollView and initialize it in viewDidLoad method of each derived view controllers. Also move activeField property to base view controller.